# add and update table using php

Tags: php, html

I am working on a webpage that takes a user's input from a form and adds it to the table below when the user clicks the submit button with HTML and PHP. right now the program works but when the user clicks the submit button the list is cleared out how can I make it so the previous item that was added to the table remains there using PHP below is my code.

```
<?php

$failure = False;

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','uobasi','blind123','mealprep');
    if(!$conn){
        echo 'Connection error: '.msqli_connect_error();
        $failure = True;
    }
$user_email = 'obasiu17@students.ecu.edu';

if(!$failure) {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $recipe = htmlspecialchars($_POST['task']);
        $sql = "insert into weeklyrecipe(username, recipe) values ('$user_email', '$recipe')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    }
}


?>


<html>
<head>
    <title> Weekly Recipes </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weeklyCalendarRepstyles.css">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Weekly Recipes</h2>
  </div>

  <form id="recipe-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="task_input">
    <select id="day" name="day">
      <option value="0">Sunday</option>
      <option value="1">Monday</option>
      <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="4">Thursday</option>
      <option value="5">Friday</option>
      <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="task_btn" name="submit">Add Recipe</button>

  </form>

  <div>
    <table id="t01">
      <tr>
        <th>Sunday</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==0){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==1){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==2){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==3){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==4){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==5){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
        <td><?php if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']==6){echo $_POST['task'];;}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You are currently display the POST data inside the table which will be replaced everytime you submit the form. You have to query the database to display all the data you submitted. You can read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) as an example how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Using **PHP session** you can get the previous record.

```
<?php
    $failure = False;
    session_start();
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','Passw0rd','mealprep');
    if(!$conn){
        echo 'Connection error: '.mysqli_connect_error();
        $failure = True;
    }
    $user_email = 'obasiu17@students.ecu.edu';
    if(!$failure) {
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          if(isset($_SESSION['weekly_recipes']) && isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']!=''){
            // check already recipes or not
            $is_recipes_available=false;
            $weekly_recipes=array();
          foreach ($_SESSION['weekly_recipes'] as $k => $data) {
                    if($_POST['day']==$data['day']){
                 $is_recipes_available=true;
                 $data['task']=$_POST['task'];
                   }    
                   array_push($weekly_recipes, $data);
              }
            if($is_recipes_available==false){
                $a=array();
                $a[0]['day']=$_POST['day'];
                $a[0]['task']=$_POST['task'];
                $_SESSION['weekly_recipes']=array_merge($_SESSION['weekly_recipes'], $a);
            }
            else{
                 $_SESSION['weekly_recipes']=$weekly_recipes;
            }
            }
        else{
            if(isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day']!=''){
                $a=array();
                $a[0]['day']=$_POST['day'];
                $a[0]['task']=$_POST['task'];
                $_SESSION['weekly_recipes']=$a;
            }
          }
          $recipe = htmlspecialchars($_POST['task']);
          unset($_POST['day']);
          unset($_POST['task']);
          $sql = "insert into weeklyrecipe(username, recipe) values ('$user_email', '$recipe')";
          mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Weekly Recipes </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weeklyCalendarRepstyles.css">

    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="heading">
        <h2>Weekly Recipes</h2>
      </div>

      <form id="recipe-form" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="task_input">
        <select id="day" name="day">
          <option value="0">Sunday</option>
          <option value="1">Monday</option>
          <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
          <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
          <option value="4">Thursday</option>
          <option value="5">Friday</option>
          <option value="6">Saturday</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="task_btn" name="submit">Add Recipe</button>

      </form>

      <div>
        <table id="t01">
          <tr>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
          </tr>
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['weekly_recipes']) && count($_SESSION['weekly_recipes'])>0){
          foreach ($_SESSION['weekly_recipes'] as $k => $data) {?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==0){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==1){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==2){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==3){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==4){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==5){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
              <td><?php if($data['day']==6){echo $data['task'];}else{ echo "-";} ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php }
        }
        else{?>
        <td><tr colspan="7">No Record Found</tr></td>
        <?php }?>     
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey this works but each time I hit submit it creates a new row how could I make it so that it won’t create a new row but add the new item under the old one like a list

Answer (score -1):

`htmlspecialchars` beter use for OUTPUT
for INPUT `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Example

```
function insert_weeklyrecipe($weeklyrecipe) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO weeklyrecipe ";
    $sql .= "(username, recipe) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'" . db_escape($conn, $weeklyrecipe['username']) . "',";
    $sql .= "'" . db_escape($conn, $weeklyrecipe['recipe']) . "'";
    $sql .= ")";  

     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // For INSERT statements, $result is true/false
    if($result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // INSERT failed
      echo mysqli_error($conn);
      exit;
    }
  }


function db_escape($conn, $string) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $string);
  }
```